# Python Selenium Chrome issue in Windows: "KLIB_SelfTest return : KLR_OK"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I made a PyQt program which runs Chrome web driver via Selenium.
It works normally in Mac or Linux, but it prints a weird line in console when I run this program on Windows, as below.

`KLIB_SelfTest return : KLR_OK`

The log itself is not a big deal, but when it comes with Pyinstaller, it produces some error when compiled by `--noconsole` option. When I remove that option it works fine, but I want the console window not to be showed.

Moreover, I'm really curious about which part of the Chrome driver produces that log. I searched almost every information as far as I can, but I couldn't find anything related with the log.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: you can use phantomjs if you dont want to show the window of the browser

Comment: @Exprator Thanks for your reply, but PhamtomJS cannot properly open local html files in my file system (starts with `file://`). My program aims for handling those kind of files. Sorry for not mentioning about that point ahead.